# Analog System.Security.Permissions in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I am trying to port project to .NET Core, but can't find analog System.Security.Permissions. Project uses construction like that

`[PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Name = "FullTrust")] or 
 [EnvironmentPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Unrestricted = true)]`,
''

Comment: I believe there are gone in CoreClr. First check the call that need them and if the APIs are still available then probably you don't need them when targeting netcoreapp1.0/netstandard. If you also need to target net451+ and they are required there you can cross compile and use `#ifdef`s

Answer (score 5):

[Code Access Security isn't and won't be available in .Net Core.](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/porting.md#code-access-security-cas) Since all code is effectively running under full trust, it should be enough to remove those attributes.

If you actually want to restrict some code, the recommendation is:

> Use operating system provided security boundaries, such as user accounts for running processes with the least set of privileges.