# System.Security.Permissions missing when invoking JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T> in .NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, json.net, .net-core

I am currently looking at using .NET Core 2.0 so that I can run my app on multiple platforms.

One thing I need to do is take an incoming string and deseralise it into an object. e.g.

```
var resultingObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyDataContract>(request);
```

In full .NET, this would run and return me my object. However in .NET Core 2.0 I get the following exception

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector.get_DynamicCodeGeneration()
 at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector.get_ReflectionDelegateFactory()
 at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.GetDefaultCreator(Type createdType)
 at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.InitializeContract(JsonContract contract)
 at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
 at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract(Type objectType)
 at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContract(Type type)
 at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
 at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
 at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
 at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
```

After some reading around I found this on StackOverflow which suggests that this kind of operation is not permitted in .NET Core https://stackoverflow.com/a/38385774/1211743

Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: For us to be able to help properly, we need a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to work with...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This was due to a lack of understanding of how .NET Core works. I opened up the csproj and added a reference to the required file 'System.Security.Permissions' and reloaded the project. At this point, nuget resolved it. Json.NET now works as expected.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I am working with .Net 4.6.1 however and this fix did not solve my problem. I am referencing System.Security and System.Security.Permissions is included in this dll. Do you have any further suggestions with this?

Comment: There is a NuGet package for it System.Security.Permissionsever it itself has issues... see https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/22423.. I reverted to use another JSON library...

Answer (score 16):

First look at the **Packages** section of your solution, most probably you will see *warnings* there:

[image]

> You should know that `NuGet` will not necessarily install the latest version for the library.
>   Especially with the  `Newtonsoft.Json` version `8.0.3` there is an issue with `System.Security.Permissions` reference, however, such an issue already doesn't exist with the `12.0.3` version.

In this case (and most probably for a lot of other cases), the solution is to right-click on the **Packages** and choose **"Manage Nuget Packages..."**.

Then click on the "Update" button:

[image]

**Rebuild** the solution(also you can try to close and open a solution too) and that's it ))

Comment: My .NET Core project had an invalid reference to the .NET Framework version dll.
I removed the package and installed the latest Nuget package for .NET Core and it worked

Answer (score 4):

I also got the same issue from a .NET framework project when a .NET Core was referencing it

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I've simply updated to Newtonsoft.Json latest available version and the issue is gone. I had the issue while migrating a lib from .net framework to .net standard and it was quite outdated.

Answer (score 3):

For me i could not connect to mysql database and i was getting this error

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51".
```

I resolved it by using nuget package manager to install Mysql.Data and also installed System.Security.Permissions. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

you need to install [System.Security.Permissions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Permissions)

I had the issue when I tried to user [AspNetCore.Reporting](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.Reporting) in a console application

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error happened because the deserialization was happening in another project with newtonsoft.json installed. Therefore, to resolve the issue, I had to install newtonsoft.json in all projects that shared newtonsoft-related functionalities.

For example, my Entities project provides access to a class named Product with a method named GetAllProducts in which JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List>(stringData) was being used. Each time I called the GetAllProducts method from another project, I got the error.

Answer (score 1):

Update or Downgrade the "System.Security.Permissions" package according to .NET Framework. (Install the System.Security.Permissions package according to the .NET Framework version.)

Comment: Or... if you're using SignalR with .NET 6, check your references are correct; see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/75667139/2250792

Answer (score 1):

While I was working with SignalR and .NET 6, attempt to call `JsonConvert.Deserialize<T>` cause exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions...

Resolved by changing reference from deprecated package `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR` v2.4.3 to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client` v7.0.3

Answer (score 0):

To see where its update place,

[image]