# How to fix issue with msg about blocked webdriver.dll when it is not blocked

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run Selenium (using WebDriver 3.1.4)  with ChromeDriver79 and it throws this error:

> Could not load webdriver.dll and webdriver.support.dll from {path} ─
>   they may be blocked (Properties>General>Unblock)

That msg is wrong, however, because...

- those files aren't blocked! (I ran Powershell's Unlock-File on them - but that did not change anything. Ok, is there a difference between "unlock" and "un**b**lock"?)
- ChromeDriver.exe instead was blocked - but even after
  unblocking it, I got the same error
- I also tested with GeckoDriver and it ran w/o problems. However, after that session I noticed that
  geckodriver.eve was locked, indeed! *(Makes me doubt about the validity
  of the whole mechanism.)* Anyway, I unlocked geckodriver and it still runs ;)

How can this problem be solved?

**Update**: I thought this was over when suddenly the message did not show up any more, I even closed the question. Unfortunately I rejoiced too early - it's back again now. And again: I am not aware that *I* changed anything in the environment. This is really painful - I will start a bounty and hope to get it resolved. This time geckodriver AND chromedriver are affected.

Comment: It would really help people understand the problem and provide possible solutions if you could add a minimum working example of the code exactly in the language you're trying to use the webdriver.

Comment: Are you making sure the webdriver instances are closed before creating the driver instance? Check if the webdriver (eg:chromedriver.exe) is running when you got the error message.

Comment: Thanks - see update and my reply: that msg was misleading, the issue lies elsewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked at it again: actually these files are not locked.

I had thought the msg came straight out of Selenium, but in fact it was the error-handler of an old subroutine which did that (I inherited that code). So, the **real** problem is this exception when instantiating ChromeDriver:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions,
>   Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

That issue has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48766856/system-security-permissions-missing-when-invoking-jsonconvert-deserializeobject) before. I'm still a bit puzzled why it would work one day and fail on the next...(will update if I find out more...)