# how to fix " Could not resolve type" error with MySQL connector in dotnet Core

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core

I'm trying to build a dotnet Core application which connects to my mysql data. 
This works fine for a dotnet Framework (on Windows), and dotNetCore (on Windows), but when I try it from dotNet Core (on Linux) I get an error saying:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 010000fd from typeref (expected class 'System.Security.PermissionSet' in assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51')
>     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open ()

My csproj file contains this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.Kinesis" Version="3.3.100.38" />
<PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.Lambda" Version="3.3.19.24" />
<PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.S3" Version="3.3.3" />
<PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.SimpleNotificationService" Version="3.3.3.26" />
<PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.SQS" Version="3.3.3.62" />
<PackageReference Include="CoreCLR-NCalc" Version="2.2.51" />
<PackageReference Include="Disruptor" Version="3.6.1" />
<PackageReference Include="ExcelDna.Integration" Version="0.34.6" />
<PackageReference Include="MathNet.Numerics" Version="4.7.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis" Version="2.10.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" Version="2.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" Version="15.0.4795.1000" />
<PackageReference Include="Mono.Data.Sqlite" Version="1.0.61" />
<PackageReference Include="MySql.Data" Version="8.0.19" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Parquet.Net" Version="3.2.4" />
<PackageReference Include="protobuf-net" Version="2.4.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.CodeDom" Version="4.7.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Collections.Immutable" Version="1.7.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Data.SQLite" Version="1.0.112" />
<PackageReference Include="System.IO.Compression" Version="4.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="unofficial.sevenziplib.codeplex" Version="9.13.5" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

How do I fix?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System.Security.Permissions missing when invoking JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T> in .NET Core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48766856/system-security-permissions-missing-when-invoking-jsonconvert-deserializeobject)

Comment: How are you adding package reference to the MySql connector library in your package?

Comment: @pso - using Nuget

Comment: @jalsh - I'm using the latest version of Mysql.Data from nuget.

Comment: @mcmillab please update the question with your .csproj file showing how you have added the package reference.

Comment: Try uninstalling the `MySql.Data` package and installing the [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) package from NuGet instead. It doesn't have the dependency on `System.Security.Permissions` for `netstandard2.0` so will likely not encounter this same `TypeLoadException`.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger I tried that, once again works for windows dotnetCore, but in Linux I now get "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Transactions.Local, Version=4.0.1.0", which isn't even something I can find in nuget

Comment: What version of .NET Core are you using, which distro and version of Linux?

Comment: dotnetCore 3.1. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

In my .net core projects, I use the `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` package for connecting with MySQL which works fine for me.

You might want to check it out if the problem persists with the current plugin.

https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql

Comment: that seems to be built on top of the same MySqlConncetor package I've tried in the comments of the original question - presumably it would have the same problems..