# Newtonsoft.Json Converter throws exception saying "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions'"

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, .net-4.5

So, I have a .NET Framework 4.5.2 Class library project in my solution that has a method to deserializate a JSON file using JsonConverter, and I have another project (that is a console window project) just to execute it.

This is the code on the class library project:

```
    public class Class1
    {
        public static void TestJson()
        {
            string json = KlausFiscal.Suite.NFSe.Resources.MunicipiosIBGE;
            IDictionary<string, string> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, string>>(json);
        }
    }
```

This is the code at the console window project:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class1.TestJson();
        }
    }
```

As I execute this program the following exception is thrown:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system can't find the file.
```

I already tried to downgrade the NewtonsoftJson version from 13.0.1 to 12.0.3 but the error persists. I've looked for the assembly that is described on the exception and it doesn't seem to be a version available for .NET Framework 4.5.2.

Anyone has any idea of what could be causing this?

Comment: Did you see [System.Security.Permissions missing when invoking JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T> in .NET Core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48766856/3744182)?  Do any of the answers there work for you?

Comment: @dbc Yes, I saw the answers to that question and tried to implement them, but unfortunately none of them worked out :/ Among the answers given on that question I thought that installing "System.Security.Permissions" throguh NuGet would be the one to solve my problem but this package doesn't have support for .Net Framework 4.5.2, only 4.6.1

Comment: Json.NET uses [`ReflectionPermission`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.permissions.reflectionpermission?view=netframework-4.5.2) and [`SecurityPermission`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.permissions.securitypermission?view=netframework-4.5.2) to test whether runtime code generation is allowed, see [JsonTypeReflector.cs](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonTypeReflector.cs#L453)...

Comment: ... In .Net Framework 4.5.2 these are part of mscorlib.dll.  Only in .Net Core is there a separate System.Security.Permissions.dll library.  Are you sure you're not trying to build a .Net Framework app using Json.NET's .Net Core DLL?

Comment: I wasn't sure so I went to check and I'm using Json.NET's pacakage that is available on NuGet, it seems that it supports the .Net Framework

Comment: It supports all the way back to .NETFramework 2.0 in fact.  But you need to get the correct build.  If you download directly from https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/13.0.1 you will see there are separate DLLs for net20, net35, net40, ***net45***, netstandard1.0, netstandard1.3 and netstandard2.0.  So be sure you are getting the correct one via nuget.