# Cannot print exception string because Exception.ToString() failed

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I am trying to connect MySql database but when executing the code it gives me this error:

Cannot print exception string because Exception.ToString() failed

```
using System;

using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;database=people;password=slidan4eg";

            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);

            conn.Open();

            string sql = "SELECT name FROM men WHERE id = 2";

            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);

            string name = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(name);

            conn.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

UPD: I was try to debug this and debugger said programm is broken on `conn.Open();`, I thought it might be important
[image]

Comment: Side point: you are missing `using` on your connection and command objects, you *must* dispose them or you will leak connections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your screenshot you have a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` and you are missing the `System.Security.Permissions` assembly. You can use the NuGet-PaketManager in Visual Studio to install it.

Comment: Thanks, I got a few other exceptions, but I solved them in the same way and now everything works)

Answer (score 1):

In case of [ExecuteScalar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) you are going to get:

1. `null` if cursor *is empty*
2. First field value from the cursor's first record if cursor is *not empty*.

**What's going on:**

The problem is in the

```
string name = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

line. If cursor is empty, `command.ExecuteScalar()` returns `null` and you have *exception thrown* on `null.ToString();` attempt

**Code:**

In your case we can exploit `Convert.ToString()` instead of `.ToString()` which *can deal* with `null`:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  string connStr = "...";

  //DONE: Dispose IDisposable with a help of using
  using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr)) {
    conn.Open();

    //DONE: let sql query be readable
    string sql = 
      @"SELECT name 
          FROM men 
         WHERE id = 2";

    using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn)) {
      // if cursor is empty we'll get null which we turn into "Not Found"
      string name = Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteScalar()) ?? "Not Found";

      Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
  }
}
```

Another possibility is null *propagation* `?.` operator. Instead of

```
string name = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

put

```
string name = command.ExecuteScalar()?.ToString() ?? "Not found";
```

Comment: None of this helped(

Comment: @Егор: according to the question *update*, you have a problem with *connection*. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48766856/system-security-permissions-missing-when-invoking-jsonconvert-deserializeobject

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the result set into a variable(of sql reader type) first, then you can read the values from that variable one by one. To pick the first record, you can follow below technique:

```
using System;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;database=people;password=slidan4eg";
            string name = "";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
            conn.Open();

            string sql = "SELECT name FROM men WHERE id = 2";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);

            var dr = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                dr.Read(); // Read first record.
                name = dr.GetString(0); // Get value of name
            }
            dr.Close();
            conn.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `.Close();` is not the correct way to dispose, you need `using` or you will leak if there is an exception