# issue using System.Security.Permissions in call to Azure DevOps using API

Tags: c#, json

I am running into an unexpected exception when trying to use an Azure DevOps API in C#.

What I am trying to do is get a list of `SecurityNameSpaces` in an Azure DevOps server.

When I get the response from the API, it is a JSON text response containing a "count" node and a "value" node. The "value" portion is an array of `SecurityNamespaceDescription` objects which is what is expected according to the Azure DevOps API documentation at Microsoft.
I don't have this issue when deserializing these types of responses for other object types (such as for TeamProjects or Identities) if I make a response root object to deserialize into.
My problem only seems to be with this one particular type of object, the `SecurityNamespaceDescription` object.

This appears to be a problem with C# being strongly typed, as I can do this operation in Powershell without any issue.

Here is what I am doing, first I make a response root object

```cs
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;

namespace azdosupport.TFSresponseModels
{
    public class SecurityNamespaceDescriptionRoot
    {
        public SecurityNamespaceDescription[] value { get; set; }   
        public int count { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is exactly the same model I use for the other valid response deserializations in my project.

But, when I try to deserialize THIS API response (which I have confirmed is a valid JSON text response) with this call:

```
 SecurityNamespaceDescriptionRoot infoblock = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SecurityNamespaceDescriptionRoot>(ResponseBody);
```

Invariably this brings up the following exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
  Source=Newtonsoft.Json
```

I have tried using the System.Security.Permissions in my System assembly packages, and also by specifically loading System.Security.Permissions Version=8.0.0.0 in my project using a nuget package.

I don't see anywhere in my project that is calling for version 0.0.0.0

As I said, since the C# operation is strongly typed, I cannot parse this list without loading and initiating the base classes, but it is failing to load them because of the version issue.
In PowerShell, the JSON conversion just builds a generic object corresponding to the JSON structure and there is no problem. I don't seem to be able to do that in C#.

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Based on your description, you have succeeded in running Azure DevOps API to get the response like in the [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/security-namespaces/query?view=azure-devops-server-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#securitynamespacedescription), right? May I assume your expection is to convert the response contents into json? If yes, this is more like a `jsonconvert` issue than `Azure DevOps` issue. Please consider sharing the sample repsonse in your original post and editing the tag to engage experts from respective subcommunity for assistance. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @JeffGedney, Good day to you and have you got a chance to check my answer below. It lists the Security Namespaces' ids and names. Hope the it could meet your requirement.

Comment: This sounds more like a dependency / package management issue eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48766856/system-security-permissions-missing-when-invoking-jsonconvert-deserializeobject

Comment: Hi @AlvinZhao 
thanks. yeah the issue is not the API, it's using jsonconvert for getting the array in the value node.  
I believe there is something in the Azure devops dll that erroneously requires a specific (invalid) version of the security dll.   
that's what I am reporting as a 'bug' 

Your treatment of the value as a json array looks like a good way to workaround the issue, and I'll give it a try.

Comment: I will be testing this workaround this week, thanks

Comment: @AlvinZhao this is not working because for some reason it's returning a "Cannot find file exception" failing to find the system.text.json version 8.0.0.1 despite the fact that I added that value specifically with nuget and I verified that the file is in the location specified by the hintpath

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you have managed to call [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/security-namespaces/query?view=azure-devops-server-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#securitynamespacedescription) to list security namespaces of your collection in Azure DevOps Server; the expectation was to extract the contents from the `value` section of the response. Here is a sample for your reference to extract the key information of a security name space. Still it is more like a `json-convert` issue rather than `Azure DevOps`.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Replace the following values with your server URL and PAT
            string serverUrl = "http://{Instance}/DefaultCollection/";
            string pat = "XXXXX";

            // Create an HttpClient and set the base address
            using HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(serverUrl);

            // Create a HttpRequestMessage with the GET method and the API endpoint
            string apiEndpoint = "_apis/securitynamespaces?api-version=7.0";
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, apiEndpoint);

            // Add the Authorization header with the base64-encoded PAT
            string base64Pat = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($":{pat}"));
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {base64Pat}");

            // Send the request and get the response
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            // Check the status code and read the content
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                // Parse the content as a JSON object
                JsonDocument json = JsonDocument.Parse(content);

                // Extract the value array from the JSON object
                JsonElement value = json.RootElement.GetProperty("value");

                // Loop through the value array and display the name and namespaceId of each security namespace
                foreach (JsonElement element in value.EnumerateArray())
                {
                    string name = element.GetProperty("name").GetString();
                    string namespaceId = element.GetProperty("namespaceId").GetString();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {name}, NamespaceId: {namespaceId}");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Display the status code and reason phrase
                Console.WriteLine($"Status code: {response.StatusCode}, Reason: {response.ReasonPhrase}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]